# Trying to solve MNIST problem using only numpy, but have accuracy near 10%

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I traing to solve MNIST problem using only numpy but have accuracy 10%
Read data and normalizing

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import pandas as pd
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot

np.random.seed(42)
# Generate mock input and output data
num_samples = 42000
input_dim = 784
# Normalization Data
csv_file_path = 'train.csv'

mnist = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

# Define a regular expression to match column names
column_pattern = r'^pixel\d{1,3}$'

# Use the filter() method to select columns based on the regular expression
selected_columns = mnist.filter(regex=column_pattern)

scaler = MinMaxScaler()
# Normalize the selected columns
normalized_selected_columns = pd.DataFrame((np.asfarray(selected_columns) / 255.0 * 1)+0.01, columns=selected_columns.columns)


X = normalized_selected_columns.values
y = mnist['label'].to_numpy()[:,np.newaxis]

# Set the number of columns you want to select (N)
N = 100

# Get the total number of columns in the array
num_columns = X.shape[0]

# Randomly select N indices without replacement
selected_indices = np.random.choice(num_columns, size=N, replace=False)

X_test = X[selected_indices,:]
Y_test = mnist['label'][selected_indices]
print(Y_test)
print(X_test.min())
```

All basic functions for train NN (code can work with custom units and layers)

```
def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

def sigmoid_derivative(x):
    return sigmoid(x) * (1 - sigmoid(x))

def softmax(Z):
  A = np.exp(Z) / sum(np.exp(Z))
  return A
def softmax_derivative(Z):    
    dZ = np.exp(Z) / sum(np.exp(Z)) * (1. - np.exp(Z) / sum(np.exp(Z)))
    return dZ

def create_simple_nn(input_size, num_layers, num_units):
    nn = {}
    
    # Initialize weights and biases for each layer
    nn['weights'] = [np.random.randn(num_units[0], num_units[1])]
    nn['biases'] = [np.zeros((1, num_units[1]))]
    
    for _ in range(1, num_layers - 1):
        nn['weights'].append(np.random.randn(num_units[_], num_units[_+1]))
        nn['biases'].append(np.zeros((1, num_units[_+1])))
    
    # Output layer weights and biases
    nn['weights'].append(np.random.randn( num_units[len(num_units) - 2],num_units[len(num_units) - 1]))
    nn['biases'].append(np.zeros((1, num_units[len(num_units) - 1])))
    
    return nn

def forward_propagation(X, nn):
    activations = [X]
    zs = []
    
    for i in range(0,len(nn['weights'])):
        Z = np.dot(activations[i], nn['weights'][i]) + nn['biases'][i]
        A = sigmoid(Z)
        activations.append(A)
        zs.append(Z)
    
    return activations, zs

def backward_propagation(X, y, activations, zs, nn, learning_rate):
    num_layers = len(nn['weights']) - 1
    m = y.shape[0]
    # Normalization Value
    normalization_value = np.sum(nn['weights'][-1]**2)/nn['weights'][-1].size

    # Compute output layer error and gradient
    dA = 2* (y - activations[-1]) / activations[-1].shape[0]
    dZ = dA * softmax_derivative(activations[-1])
    dW = np.dot(activations[-2].T, dZ) / m
    db = np.sum(dZ, axis=0, keepdims=True) / m
    nn['weights'][-1] -= learning_rate * dW
    nn['biases'][-1] -= learning_rate * db
    
    # Backpropagate the error through hidden layers
    for l in range(num_layers - 1, 0, -1):
        dA_prev = np.dot(dZ, nn['weights'][l+1].T)
        dZ = dA_prev * sigmoid_derivative(activations[l+1])
        dW = np.sum(np.dot(activations[l].T, dZ),axis=0,keepdims=True) / m
        db = np.sum(dZ, axis=0, keepdims=True) / m
        nn['weights'][l] -= learning_rate * dW
        nn['biases'][l] -= learning_rate * db
    return dA
def train_nn(X, y, nn, learning_rate, epochs):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        chooses = np.random.choice(X.shape[0],10000,replace=False)
        X_chooses = X[chooses,:]
        y_chooses = y[chooses]
        activations, zs = forward_propagation(X_chooses, nn)
        accuracy = backward_propagation(X_chooses, y_chooses, activations, zs, nn, learning_rate)
        if (epoch%10==0):
            print('Epoch: {0}, Accuracy: {1}'.format(epoch, np.sum(accuracy)/y_chooses.shape[0]))
```

Train NN

```
# Define network parameters
input_size = input_dim
num_layers = 3
num_units = [784,128,64,9]
learning_rate = 0.00001
epochs = 10000

# Create the neural network
nn = create_simple_nn(input_size, num_layers, num_units)

# Train the neural network
train_nn(X, y, nn, learning_rate, epochs)
```

I try change activations functions, change learning rate, change my activation function to RELU from sigmoid.
I try to debug my code but cannot see solution for my problem